# How to rename a key in Julia dictionary?

Tags: julia

I have a dictionary in Julia:

```
d = Dict(1 => "A", 2 => "B", 3 => "D")
```

where I have deleted a key and its value such that:

```
delete!(d, "1")
```

Now, I want to re-order the remaining keys as `d = Dict(1 => "B", 2 => "D")`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

In your question keys are `Int`s so the delete operation should be:

```
delete!(d, 1)
```

Now to move indices the best way is to rebuild the dictionary:

```
julia> d2 = Dict(keys(d) .- 1 .=> values(d))
Dict{Int64, String} with 2 entries:
  2 => "D"
  1 => "B"
```

Comment: Beautiful map operator `.`. I'm in love with it.

Comment: Is there a way to change keys in place, rather than create a whole new dictionary? I'm asking because in my case the dictionary is very big and storing two copies of it exceeds my RAM.

Comment: You could change the keys one-by-one. However you cannot update the key (you need to drop and recreate it). Perhaps you need another data structure depending on your use case scenario?

Comment: Indeed. Deleting and creating a new (key, value) pair one-by-one should work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using broadcasting for rebuilding the dictionary is to use a generator:

```
julia> Dict((key-1) => val for (key, val) in d)
Dict{Int64, String} with 2 entries:
  2 => "B"
  3 => "D"
```

This appears to be faster, too, though this is a very small example to test on:

```
julia> @btime Dict(keys(d) .- 1 .=> values($d))
  913.333 ns (13 allocations: 944 bytes)

julia> @btime Dict((key-1)=>val for (key, val) in $d)
  150.244 ns (4 allocations: 528 bytes)
```